# Disadvantages to Web Api methods returning Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task, taskfactory

Why is the practice of returning a `Task<T>` from Web Api methods not the default and in the methods that you get when you create a new Web Api Controller in Visual Studio?

Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public Task<string> Boo()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return "Boo";
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that Task.Factory.StartNew is not really async in the sense you want (i.e. releasng the thread); it just runs on a background thread so gives you no actual benefit, it just adds overhead. If you were hell-bent on always returning Task, you could use Task.FromResult, which would just make your method run fully sync. And then you'd need to ask yourself why you are bothering to make it more verbose and less clear.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Yes, you're making your code less readable, longer and less performant for no good reason. I don't see any *adavantages* of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

When to use asynchronous operations:

- Your application has to query data from *external* sources (external services, databases,..). Using asynchronous operations with `Task` is this case is key to **scalable applications** as your threads are not blocked waiting for the external sources.
- You need to do a lot of compute-bound operations. Since compute-bound operations occur on CPU, parallelizing these operations can greatly improve the application throughput, especially if your application is run on a multi-core computer.

With that being said, we do not always use async: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

A typical case is we don't need to query data from external sources, it's already there:

> It can actually benefit a developer to avoid using
>   async methods in a certain, small set of use cases, particularly for
>   library methods that will be accessed in a more fine-grained manner.
>   Typically, this is the case when it’s known that the method may
>   actually be able to complete synchronously because **the data it’s
>   relying on is already available**.

Asynchronous operations with `Task` does have overhead:

> When designing asynchronous methods, the Framework developers spent a
>   lot of time optimizing away object allocations. This is because
>   allocations represent one of the largest performance costs possible in
>   the asynchronous method infrastructure. The act of allocating an
>   object is typically quite cheap. Allocating objects is akin to filling
>   your shopping cart with merchandise, in that it doesn't cost you much
>   effort to put items into your cart; it’s when you actually check out
>   that you need to pull out your wallet and invest significant
>   resources. **While allocations are usually cheap, the resulting garbage
>   collection can be a showstopper when it comes to the application’s
>   performance**.